# how to clone images of drives with LUKS+LVM2?

Tags: luks, lvm, disk-image, clonezilla, disk-encryption

I have 2 Debian boxes which I need to upgrade. In the past, before upgrading any box, I have used [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) to create an image of each of the box's harddrives for use as disaster backup, in case Something Goes Wrong with the upgrade. (Note I regularly create file-backups (with `duplicity` and `rsync`) of my `/home` filesystem and config files: I only create image-backups before major events, like upgrades or reinstalls.) However, I recently noted [this response to a Clonezilla forum post](https://sourceforge.net/p/clonezilla/discussion/Help/thread/54c8786a/#7ab3) (from [one of the Clonezilla leads](https://sourceforge.net/u/userid-704891/):

```
RAID device is complicated to Clonezilla live, besides
LUKS is not supported by Clonezilla, either. Therefore
your configuration is too difficult for Clonezilla
```

The harddrives on the boxes I want to image do *not* run RAID, but they do run both LUKS+LVM2 (installed as described [here](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/install_resizable_encrypted_lmde)). So I'd like to know, how are folks with similar setups cloning their drives?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have the disk space, I would just go with `dd` which will do a byte for byte copy of the drive. If you are not familiar with `dd`, it's fequently described as a dangerous command. The arguments for source and destination are `if=` and `of=` (for input file and output file) and if you mix them up you get no warning, rather you just overwrite your good drive.